# Save audio file to desired path

Tags: python, file, audio, path, mp3

I have a lot of text-to-speech audio files that I need to save but often, the files get lost.
Currently I'm using

```
    import gtts
    from playsound import playsound
   
    def say(speech):
        tts = gtts.gTTS(speech)
        tts.save("audio.mp3")
        playsound("audio.mp3")
```

Is there any way that I can save the mp3 to wherever I desire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can  just paste content of new audio  file into another file like below:

```
import gtts
from playsound import playsound

def say(speech):
    tts = gtts.gTTS(speech)
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    playsound("audio.mp3")

    # PLACE CONTENT INTO NEW FILE => S T A R T
    main_file =  open("audio.mp3", "rb").read()
    dest_file = open('path/to_your/file_name.mp3', 'wb+')
    dest_file.write(main_file)
    dest_file.close()
    # PLACE CONTENT INTO NEW FILE => E N D
```

or

```
import gtts
from playsound import playsound
import shutil

def say(speech):
    tts = gtts.gTTS(speech)
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    playsound("audio.mp3")

    # PLACE CONTENT INTO NEW FILE => S T A R T
    shutil.move("audio.mp3", "path/to_your/file_name.mp3")
    # PLACE CONTENT INTO NEW FILE => E N D
```

Comment: Why? Documentation says you can just use the `save` method with an included path. https://gtts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html?highlight=sav#gtts.tts.gTTS.save

Comment: I  can't say definite since I didn't used  playsound library before . But this answer may be good working alternative  also.

Comment: The issue with the answer is that it saves the file twice, once in the current directory and once in the destination directory. Either edit the answer to delete the original file after copying, or just copy the file directly (no duplicatin)

Comment: Finally I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the directory you need in the brackets when you save tts as mp3 file:

`tts.save("directory/that/you/want/audio.mp3")`

Answer (score 0):

Just create folder by yourself or with your app and write:

```
from gtts import gTTS

tts.save("c:/folder/audioname.mp3")# use the "/" while setting the path
```

thats just an example. You can change the disk but you have to mention it with a  small letter (d:, f:, c:)

Answer (score -1):

I did like this:  s.save("your folder name/audio.mp3")